# Jquery UI Accordion, Correct way of getting the index of a known element by id only within the list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to get the index (in terms of accordion selection index) of a known element. I have its ID.

The best I have come up with so far is pre arranging the node to be a jquery object like so:

`var node = $('#'+uuidIHave)`

then I search over the list and massage a zero into the base match (which returns 1 more than the others)

```
var num = $('#accordion').children().index(node);
// test for dom misses 
if ( typeof num !== "undefined"){
//Test for the miss
if(num != -1){   
var derivedIndex = parseInt( Math.floor((1.0 * num) * 0.5)); 
$('#accordion').accordion( "option", "active", derivedIndex );
}}
```

this seems to work but...
is there not an easier way?

thanks :)

the DOM for an accordion looks thusly FWIW

```
<div id="accordion">
<h3 id="foo">First header</h3>
<div>First content panel</div>
<h3 id="bar">Second header</h3>
<div>Second content panel</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does the DOM look like? What exactly do you mean *"in terms of accordion selection index"*..? I don't understand why you're doing all this and what exactly you want...

Comment: the DOM is the same for all accordion instances. I am citing the most basic of examples.   
which can be found here https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/
`<div id="accordion"> <h3 id="foo">First header</h3> <div>First content panel</div> <h3 id="bar">Second header</h3><div>Second content panel</div>`
`</div>`

How do I get an index value that I could pass back to the accordion to select "foo" as selected.  and also "bar"

Comment: The DOM is the same in terms of .children().index(node). I am doing all this to enable me to open an accordion whilst only knowing the ID of the thing I wish to open.  The code above works. It just seems counter-intuitive.  Not sure how I can be any clearer than working code of my intentions :)